# Compiler not understanding recursive function to print tree level-order C++

Tags: c++, class, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I'm currently attempting to solve the following problem:

Write a function void TreeNode::levelOrder(int n) with wrapper void Tree::levelOrder() to print a tree level-order using recursion

This is the class header:

```
#ifndef TREE_H
#define TREE_H

#include <algorithm>

class TreeNode {
  private:
    int key;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;

  public:
    TreeNode(int key);
    void insert(int key);
    void display(TreeNode *p, int lvl);
    void preOrder();
    void inOrder();
    void postOrder();

    int  size();
    int  height();
};

class Tree {
  private:
    TreeNode *root;
  public:
    Tree();
    Tree(int *a, int n);
    void insert(int key);
    void preOrder();
    void inOrder();
    void postOrder();
    void display(TreeNode *p);
    int  size();
    int  height();
};

void TreeNode::display(TreeNode *p, int lvl){
    if (p!=NULL){
        if (p->left)  display(p->left,  lvl + 4);
        if (p->right) display(p->right, lvl + 4);
    if (lvl) {
        std::cout << std::setw(lvl) << ' ';
    }
    cout << p->key << "\n";
    } 
}

void Tree::display(TreeNode *p){
    if (p!=NULL){
        return display(p,0);
}
```

With these two functions, I am still getting the following error:

"./Tree.h:139:20: error: too many arguments to function call, expected single
      argument 'p', have 2 arguments
                return display(p,3);
                       ~~~~~~~   ^
./Tree.h:137:1: note: 'display' declared here
void Tree::display(TreeNode *p){    "

I don't understand why the compiler can't recognize to call the function from TreeNode class with **2 arguments**.  Instead, the compiler is telling me the recursive function should only expect one argument.
I know I'm most likely not understanding the bigger picture here so could anyone try and clear this issue up for me?  Thanks alot.

Comment: Your post is missing the actual error.

Comment: Educated guess, though, you can't `return` the result of a `void` function; it does not have a result to return.

Comment: Though, I also don't see `display` in either class declaration

Comment: It was in the actual code just forgot to throw it in this post.  However, axiac's solution cleared up the error for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in this method:

```
void Tree::display(TreeNode *p){
    if (p!=NULL){
        return display(p,0);
}
```

`return display(p,0);` means `return this->display(p,0);` and the compiler is right.

What you probably meant is `p->display(p, 0);`.

---

As a side note, the `display()` methods in both classes seem to be static methods (and they don't have any reason to be); they don't use the properties of the object used to invoke them.

In order to be correct OOP, you should rewrite them as follows:

```
void TreeNode::display(int lvl)
{
    if (left) {
        left->display(lvl + 4);
    }
    if (right) {
        right->display(lvl + 4);
    }
    if (lvl) {
        std::cout << std::setw(lvl) << ' ';
    }
    cout << key << "\n";
}

void Tree::display(){
    if (root) {
        root->display(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, this cleared up the issue for me.  I get why the p must point to that function as well.. Thanks!

Comment: Right, that actually answers the question above for me too.  I couldn't figure out how to implement the method without the node pointer as an argument.  Makes the solution much simpler too